# Element wider than its parent not shown during jQuery slide animation

Tags: jquery, css

When showing (using jQuery UI's show) a #content element with a child #footer wider than #content, the #footer part outside #content appears only once the animation is finished, while everything within #content is already shown during the animation. Why? Anybody can help?

Thanks

Jul

Comment: It doesn't look like an erroneous error... It simply looks like it is waiting for the animation to complete. If you could single out some code that only pertains to this issue, you will get more responses.

Comment: You're right, it's waiting for the animation to complete. I'll edit my question accordingly. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Animate sets overflow:hidden during the animation.  You can try setting `overflow:visible !important` in your css.

Comment: The #content element is wrapped by a .ui-effects-wrapper element during the animation, so I have to set overflow:visible !important to that wrapper element. But then the animation is visible outside the #content element (from the top to the bottom of the screen). That's painful. Thanks anyway, it helped a lot!