# Issue with jQuery UI animation overflow

Tags: jquery-ui, animation, overflow

I've got an element `#content` and a child element `#footer` positioned outside `#content`. When animating `#content`, `#footer` is not visible during the animation. I've understood from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899601/element-wider-than-its-parent-not-shown-during-jquery-slide-animation) that this was because the animation set overflow to hidden during the animation. I've then set the overflow of the wrapper created by jQuery UI (`.ui-effects-wrapper`) to `overflow: visible !important;`, but then the animated element is also visible outside `#content` during the animation.

So: I need `overflow: visible` to see my `#footer` element, but jQuery UI needs `overflow: hidden` to hide the animated part outside `#content`.

Anybody can help?

Thanks

```
#content {
    position: absolute;
    width: 45em;
    height: 26em;
    top: 8em;
    left: 16em;
}

#footer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200em;  //larger than #content, so have to play with overflow
    height: 2.375em;
    bottom: 0;
    left: -50em;
}

.ui-effects-wrapper {
    overflow: visible !important ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

During the animation you can change the visibility.  Example:

```
$('#link').click(function(){
    // Do the animation

    $(this).css('overflow','visible');
});
```

Would that help?

Comment: When setting overflow to visible for the jQuery-UI wrapper element, my footer is visible during the animation, but the animation becomes ugly, because the animated element is *entirely* visible during the animation (even outside its original position).